# Extend the Ubuntu disk space that was installed beside Windows 7 without reinstalling

Tags: disk

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 inside windows from Ubuntu CD with 12 GB space. How could I increase the disk space to 20 GB with out reinstalling Ubuntu ?

Comment: Dupe of @fossfreedom's one. @Lekensteyn, that one refers to a standalone install.

Answer (score 2):

([answer taken from SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/125990/how-to-increase-disk-space-in-wubi-ubuntu-via-windows))

According to this [guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How%20do%20I%20resize%20the%20virtual%20disks?), you can use [LVPM](http://lubi.sourceforge.net/lvpm.html)

As an alternative, you can use the following script to move /home to a dedicated virtual disk.

Download [wubi-add-virtual-disk](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=wubi-add-virtual-disk), open a terminal and run:

```
sudo sh wubi-add-virtual-disk /home 15000
```

Where the first argument is the directory to move to a new dedicated disk, and the second argument is the size in MB.

You should now reboot. If you are happy with the result, you can now remove /home.backup. To undo the changes remove /home, copy rename /home.backup to /home and remove the /home line in /etc/fstab.